# Jmeter load test is not getting over at given time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm running Jmeter load test from command prompt for about one hour and test is not ending at one hour. It is taking more time that one hour.

I'm getting errors in Jmeter logs for failed transactions:

```
Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException 

Non HTTP response message: Unexpected end of file from server
```

Please advise. Is it because of some threads is hanging and how to rectify it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you find where it's stuck? what's the problematic request? it can be a bug in your application or problem with socket timeouts definition

Comment: the request was to check the response of application by applying load for 1 hour after applying patches and some thread is not responding and I'm assuming because of that it is not completing in given time. Please guide me here.

Comment: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException - getting this error message

Comment: can you give full stack trace? is the exception in jmeter or in your app?

Comment: when I checked Jmeter response logs for application it is showing the above error for failed transactions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Non HTTP response message: Unexpected end of file from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you didn't set Connect and Read Timeout in Http Request default.
So if you server hangs, JMeter will wait infinitely for the response.

Beside ensure you set correct values in your scheduler.

If issue persists, please give more details with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter "asks" threads to stop and waits for their graceful shutdown. If threads cannot be stopped in a timely fashion you have the following options:

1. Implement a "hard stop", i.e. instead of "asking" threads to stop you need to "tell" them to stop. It can be done using i.e. [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler with `Stop now` action. (remember that in this case JMeter won't wait for graceful shutdown and you will get extra errors connected with abnormal threads termination)
2. The fact that JMeter threads are stuck may indicate problem with your application so I would recommend checking baseline health metrics on the application under test side using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](http://How%20to%20Monitor%20Your%20Server%20Health%20&%20Performance%20During%20a%20JMeter%20Load%20Test). If there is enough headroom but it still works slowly or doesn't work at all it might indicate a bottleneck in your application code or infrastructure.
3. Also make sure you are following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and make sure your JMeter load generator(s) have enough CPU, RAM, etc. as in some cases JMeter can report "false negative" results due to lack of hardware resources.